# update table column with different random numbers

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query

```
UPDATE f1
SET col = (SELECT ABS(300 + RANDOM() % 3600))
```

that update the "col" column with a random number between 300 and 3600.
But it returns the same random number for all the rows. Is there a way to update the rows with different random numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's using the same random number because the subquery only needs to run once for the UPDATE.  In other words, the SQL engine knows that the inner SELECT only needs to be run once for the query; it does so, and uses the resultant value for each row.

You actually don't need a subquery.  This will do what you want:

```
UPDATE f1
SET col = ABS(300 + RANDOM() % 3600);
```

but if for some reason you really do want a subquery, you just need to make sure that it's dependent upon the rows in the table being updated.  For example:

```
UPDATE f1
SET col = (SELECT (col*0) + ABS(300 + RANDOM() % 3600));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this which worked for me in oracle database. 
For Example, use query below if you want to have four digit random number using RPAD :

`Update tableName set ColName=RPAD(round(dbms_random.value(0,9999)),4,'0');`

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest adding a WHERE clause in which you use an attribute to distinguish the rows.
For example, suppose you have a column row_id and you want to update only the rows with 1 in the row_id, the code you'd use would be similar to:

```
UPDATE f1
SET col = (SELECT ABS(300 + RANDOM() % 3600))
WHERE row_id = 1
```

The resulting table would be something like:

```
row_id    |   col     |
   1      |   200     |
```

In which the value in the "col" column would correspond to the random number.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to solve the problem by writing an SQL procedure, like the following one:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name()
BEGIN
    DECLARE c int ;
    SET c = 1 ;
    WHILE c< (SELECT MAX(row_id) FROM f1) DO
      UPDATE f1 
        SET col = SELECT ABS(300 + RANDOM() % 3600)
        WHERE row_id = c;
      SET c = c + 1 ;
    END WHILE ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```